# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException Spring Data + JPA + Hibernate

Tags: oracle11g, java-8, spring-data-jpa, c3p0, hibernate-entitymanager

I´m trying to do an example of Spring Data following the documentation...But i got an NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in the repository Interface, it does not appear be proxified neither contained in spring container...Here my example:

This is my **POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mx.com.segal</groupId>
  <artifactId>middleware</artifactId>
  <version>0.01</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>middleware</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>          
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
    <environment>development</environment>
    <app.main.class>mx.com.segal.front.App</app.main.class>
    <platform>windows</platform>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <logger.version>1.1.7</logger.version>
    <logger.facade.version>1.7.21</logger.facade.version>
  </properties>

   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <type>maven-plugin</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.facade.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency> 
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.version}</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
              <environment>development</environment>
             </properties>
        </profile>      
        <profile>
            <id>pro</id>
            <properties>
              <environment>production</environment>       
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

  <build>
     <filters>          
            <filter>
                src/main/discriminators/${platform}_${environment}.properties
            </filter>
     </filters>
     <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>                 
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
     </resources>
     <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
               <source>${java.version}</source>
               <target>${java.version}</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>${app.main.class}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is my **Spring conf** files:

**middleware.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">   
    <context:component-scan base-package="mx.com.segal" />          
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>middleware/properties/messages</value>
                <value>default</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns=             "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi=         "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:tx=          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context=     "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa=         "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" 
       xmlns:p=           "http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd">
    <import resource="middleware.xml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="mx.com.segal.persist.repository" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="mx.com.segal.persist.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${driver.class}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${datasource.usuario}" />
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.pass}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
          p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter"
          p:packagesToScan="mx.com.segal.persist.model">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="jpa.showSql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" /> 
                <!-- <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics" value="true" /> -->
                <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
                <entry key="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
          p:database="ORACLE" p:showSql="true" p:generateDdl="false" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans>
```

**This is my Repository Interface:**

```
package mx.com.segal.persist.repository.city;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import mx.com.segal.persist.model.Ciudad;

@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<Ciudad, String>{

    @Query("select c from Ciudad c where c.dsCiudad like :dsCiudad||'%' ")
    List<Ciudad> findByDescripcion(@Param("dsCiudad") String dsCiudad);
}
```

This is my **Entity pojo**:

```
package mx.com.segal.persist.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "D_CIUDAD")
public class Ciudad implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID_D_CIUDAD")
    private String codCiudad;

    @Column(name="DS_CIUDAD")
    private String dsCiudad;

    public Ciudad() {
    }

    public String getCodCiudad() {
        return this.codCiudad;
    }

    public void setCodCiudad(String codCiudad) {
        this.codCiudad = codCiudad;
    }

    public String getDsCiudad() {
        return this.dsCiudad;
    }

    public void setDsCiudad(String dsCiudad) {
        this.dsCiudad = dsCiudad;
    }

}

**This my service pojo:**

package mx.com.segal.persist.service.city.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import mx.com.segal.persist.repository.city.CityRepository;
import mx.com.segal.persist.service.city.ICityService;
import mx.com.segal.persist.model.Ciudad;

@Service
public class CityServiceImpl implements ICityService {

 @Autowired 
 private CityRepository cityRepository;

  public List<Ciudad> getListaCiudades(){ 
      return  (List<Ciudad>)cityRepository.findAll();
  }

  public List<Ciudad> getByDescripcion(String desc){
     return (List<Ciudad>)cityRepository.findByDescripcion(desc);
  }

}
```

One more class for **managing** requests...

```
@Component
public class CityManagerImpl implements ICityManager{

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    @Autowired
    private ICityService cityServiceImpl;

    @Override
    public List<Ciudad> getCities() {
        logger.debug("Listado de ciudades");
        return cityServiceImpl.getListaCiudades();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Ciudad> getCityByDesc(String desc) {
        logger.debug("Listado de ciudades por descripcion");
        return cityServiceImpl.getByDescripcion(desc);
    }

}
```

**Now i call it from an App class:**

```
/**
 * Middleware App runner;
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    private static final String[] CONTEXT = new String[] { "context/middleware.xml" };
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("mx.com.segal.front.App");

    public App(){
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONTEXT);
    }

    public static void main( String... args )
    {

        App p=new App();
        ISimpleManager simple=(ISimpleManager)p.context.getBean("simpleManager");
        ICityManager cityManager=(ICityManager)p.context.getBean("cityManagerImpl");
        List<Ciudad> ciudades=cityManager.getCities();
        for(Ciudad city : ciudades){
            logger.debug("Codigo: "+city.getCodCiudad()+" Descripcion: "+city.getDsCiudad());
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally the exception excerpt:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private mx.com.segal.persist.service.city.ICityService mx.com.segal.back.city.impl.CityManagerImpl.cityServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private mx.com.segal.persist.repository.city.CityRepository mx.com.segal.persist.service.city.impl.CityServiceImpl.cityRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [mx.com.segal.persist.repository.city.CityRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Any advice? **CityRepository** appear don´t be available for the example...

Comment: Resolved, i forgot to call persistence.xml in middleware.xml, with <import resource="persistence.xml"/>

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

I added this line in middleware.xml

```
<import resource="persistence.xml"/>
```